# cookie is being stored as different value

Tags: users, cookies

I have the following code:

```
if(isset($ret["token"])) {
    drupal_set_message("TOKEN: " . $ret["token"]); 
    user_cookie_save(array("my_token"=>$ret["token"])); 
    drupal_set_message("KEY: " . $_COOKIE['Drupal_visitor_my_token']);
  }
```

Here is the printout of values:

```
TOKEN: 339497878
KEY: 354541465
```

Why am I getting different values?

Comment: why the down vote?

Comment: Probably for similar reason as the close vote? It's pretty basic question about how pretty basic aspect of HTTP works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_COOKIE` superglobal contains values that was in cookies at the moment of HTTP request. Setting new cookies does not affect / update this array - new value will be available at *next* page load.